# Replace <c:if> and fn:toUpperCase() with JSF-tags

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, facelets

This example is from a book on JSF. The excercise is to refactor the following Facelets code while eliminating `<c:if>` and `fn:toUpperCase()`. Usage of `<c:forEach>` is allowed.

`#{myBean.numbers}` returns `String["one","two","three"]`

As the book is on JSF and not on Java, I suppose the existing Java-code is not to be touched. But I can't think of another way to do this solely in Facelets.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="#{myBean.numbers}">
    <c:if test="#{not fn:endsWith(item,'o')}">
        #{item}
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{fn:endsWith(item,'o')}">
        #{fn:toUpperCase(item)}
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Only thing I can think of is using a converter that conditionally uses `String#toUpperCase()` and then I still do not understand why use of `<c:forEach>` should still be allowed:

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{myBean.numbers}">
     <h:outputText value="#{item}" converter="conditionalConverter"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Is there a more "Facelets way" to do this (and still a need to use `<c:forEach>`)?

**UPDATE:**
Instead of `<c:if>` one could still use e.g. `<h:outputPanel>` and it's `rendered`-attribute, but there is still no Java-less replacement for `fn:toUpperCase()`.

I am asking for learning purposes only. I suppose the `<ui:repeat>`-solution with a converter is the cleanest and represents most how JSF is supposed to be used. Do you think so, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to `<c:if>`, the JSF alternative to JSTL `<c:if>` is the `rendered` attribute on any component. For example, `<h:panelGroup>` or `<h:outputText>`. Those components doesn't generate additional markup if there are no attribtues specified which should end up in HTML, like `id` or `styleClass`, otherwise they generate a `<span>`.

Here's an example of both:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not fn:endsWith(item,'o')}">
    #{item}
</h:panelGroup>
<h:outputText value="#{fn:toUpperCase(item)}" rendered="#{fn:endsWith(item,'o')}" />
```

As to `fn:toUpperCase()`, JSF has no alternative. I'm not sure why you would need a JSF alternative as it's essentially not a tag, but a simple EL function which is perfectly usable in both JSTL and JSF tags. In any case, you could if necessary throw in CSS `text-transform: uppercase`. As this takes place entirely client side, your only problem may be the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-transform).

```
<h:outputText value="#{item}" style="text-transform: uppercase" />
```

*(note: this is just an example, the normal practice is to put styles in its own `.css` file which you load by `<h:outputStylesheet>`)*

```
<h:outputText value="#{item}" styleClass="uppercased" />
```

---

> *I suppose the -solution with a converter is the cleanest and represents most how JSF is supposed to be used. Do you think so, too?*

I'm a big fan of "Use the right tool for the job". Use JSTL tags to conditionally build the JSF component tree. Use JSF components to generate HTML. That's it. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: h:panelGroup is not a replacement for c:if. 
h:panelGroup adds a <span> tag in your html code, which groups tags inside. This is useless crap in your html code in the best case, and can be problematic in others

Comment: @Rober2D2: perhaps you forgot to read the 1st paragraph of the answer?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read. In any case, if you want to "update" that precise part, you must use an id. Plus you don't have an else condition like in <c:choose>.  I will work with rendered as there is no alternative, but I still think is a poor substitute for JSTL.